# Is there a way to iteratively add a list to a graph in rdflib?

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib

I have lists of literals that I would like to add as rdf:lists to a graph. I can read rdf:lists without issue using rdflib.collection.Collection, but I haven't been able to add those lists to other graphs, or iteratively generate an rdf:list from a python list.

Does rdflib have any functionality like this?

Update: I went back through the docs and found a solution using Collection.

```
from rdflib.graph import Graph, BNode, Collection, Literal, RDF, Namespace
listName = BNode()
EX = Namespace('http://www.example.org/')
g.bind('ex', EX)
g = Graph()
listo = [1,2,356,4]
c = Collection(g,EX.name,[Literal(x) for x in listo])
```

Answer (score 2):

if `c = Collection(g,EX.name,[Literal(x) for x in listo])` solves the question, please mark it solved so people know to visit it for an answer if they have the same question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

`c = Collection(g,EX.name,[Literal(x) for x in listo])`